# NPAPI Plugin to intercept web requests?

Tags: npapi, browser-extension

Is there a way to create a NPAPI plugin that intercepts web requests from the parent browser?  I want to see that Chrome/Safari/IE/etc is requesting http://google.com/ or whatever, and then provide my own response to this query.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't really do this with npapi. Firstly what content the browser uses your plugin for is based solely on mime type.

Secondly once the browser has decided to use plugin X to display something the api doesn't provide you with a way of telling the browser that  you (the plugin) doesn't actually want to display the content. Implementing a whole browser within your plugin might work but seems very overkill and would no doubt have many caveats.

If I were you I would be looking at chrome/safari/Firefox extensions

Comment: In firefox this is possible, but I haven't figure out how to do it in Safari or Chrome.  Any tips would be great :D

Comment: This is *not* possible with an NPAPI plugin; you need an extension for this. You might be writing the extension in C++ and using parts of NPAPI to help with it, but you are certainly not using NPAPI to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with the NPAPI, you seem to be mixing up [*extensions* and *plugins*](http://colonelpanic.net/2010/08/browser-plugins-vs-extensions-the-difference/).

NPAPI allows you to write browser plugins, which are embedded in a page or used for full-page content display to provide content or scripting capabilities. Most importantly, plugins have to be explicitly embedded in pages or loaded for specific mime-types and don't have control over their life-time.

Extensions on the other hand extend the browser, can stay active independently of the specific page content and catch events like navigation etc. (details depend on the extension API the browser offers).